# finding release point and angle from given target point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm creating a small catapult physics game.

If I have a release point to work with such as:

```
start.X = 12
start.Y = 962
Angle = 74
Gives us:
end.X = 545
end.Y = 295
```

how would I work out the start.X, start.Y and Angle for any other given end.X and end.Y from the above numbers? Would I need more Data?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no air friction in the model, then the shape of the flight path is, as Galileo first computed, a parabola. Since Newton we know the equations of motion, which are 
\begin{align}
x(t)&=x_0+u⋅t\\
y(t)&=y_0+v⋅t-\tfrac g2⋅ t^2
\end{align}

The initial angle $α$ gives the relation $u=\tanα ⋅ v$. Elimination of $t$ gives
$$
\tanα(y(t)-y_0)=(x(t)-x_0)+\frac g2\frac{(x(t)-x_0)^2}{u^2}
$$
This allows to compute $\frac{u}{\sqrt{g}}$ from the given data, and thus the trajectory.

However, you might reach the same point using different angles by changing the inital velocity, so your task is not clearly defined. But for instance it would be sufficient to demand that the size of the inital velocity is always the same, i.e., $c^2=u^2+v^2$ is constant, $u=c\cosα$, $v=c\sinα$.